Do we need to create index on SQL Server view to get better query performance?
I have a SQL Server table with this structure:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Row_Id] [bigint] NOT NULL, 
    [Year_Code] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Row_Values] [text] NULL,
    [Date_Refreshed] [datetime] NOT NULL,    

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable_Row_Id] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Row_Id] ASC) 
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF
) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]     
GO  

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_Date_Refreshed]
        DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Date_Refreshed] 
GO  

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyTable_Code] 
ON [dbo].[MyTable] (Year_Code ASC)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
          SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
          ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON,  
          OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

I created a view on top of this table
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_MyTable] 
AS 
    SELECT 
        JSON_VALUE(CAST([Row_Values] AS varchar(8000)), '$."id"') AS id,
        JSON_VALUE(CAST([Row_Values] AS varchar(8000)), '$."year"') AS  year_code,
        JSON_VALUE(CAST([Row_Values] AS varchar(8000)), '$."emp_id"') AS emp_id,
        JSON_VALUE(CAST([Row_Values] AS varchar(8000)), '$."emplocalid"') AS emplocalid,
        JSON_VALUE(CAST([Row_Values] AS varchar(8000)), '$."firstname"') AS firstname,
        JSON_VALUE(CAST([Row_Values] AS varchar(8000)), '$."lastname"') AS lastname,
        JSON_VALUE(CAST([Row_Values] AS varchar(8000)), '$."middlename"') AS middlename,
        JSON_VALUE(CAST([Row_Values] AS varchar(8000)), '$."dateofbirth"') AS dateofbirth,
        JSON_VALUE(CAST([Row_Values] AS varchar(8000)), '$."race"') AS race,
        JSON_VALUE(CAST([Row_Values] AS varchar(8000)), '$."gender"') AS gender     
    FROM 
        [dbo].[MyTable]

When I'm trying to query the view like this:
SELECT 
    [id], [year_code], [emp_id],
    [emplocalid], [firstname], [lastname], [middlename],
    [dateofbirth], [race], [gender]   
FROM 
    [dbo].[vw_MyTable]  
WHERE
    [year_code] = 'yr2023'

My question is: as you see I have index on the base table so in order to get better query performance, do I need to create index on the SQL Server view as well? I didn't create index on SQL Server view

Queries using the view will be able to use the index on the underlying table you already created.

Try it and find out?  But with all that json parsing, I'd suggest storing that as a table, as opposed to doing it every single time someone queries the view.

Views can be expensive, especially with larger tables.    Consider a parameter driven Table-Valued Function.

@JohnCappelletti  Thanks for the reply! can you give some example?

@Andrew  Thanks for the reply! My problem is that every year the number of columns will change that's the reason I opted for JSON.  If you think table would work, please share more details. Thank you!

You might be better off using OPENJSON. You can be much more explicit about your data types then; a nvarchar(MAX) cast to a varchar(8000) is a bad choice of data type for a date of birth. I might be recalling early version of the JSON features, but I'm sure I recall lots of JSON_VALUE calls being less performant that a single OPENJSON call.

Also text has been deprecated since 2005; it's long past time you stopped using it.

Queries can be expensive, especially with larger tables...

Also DATETIME is not reccommande and must be replaced by DATETIME2(n) with the wanted n precision for second's decimals

If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.


Do we need to create an index on the view to get good performance here?

No. To get good performance here you stop abusing JSON columns and actually define your schema for the raw table. From there, you might use one more indexes, but put them on the table itself.
